# Is there any way to get sound cloud Track ID by Share URL?

Tags: wordpress, api, iframe, embed, soundcloud

1. There is one text input field where one can pass "Share" URL of SoundCloud.
2. Sample "Share" URL: `https://soundcloud.com/alo-wala/the-coconut-song`
3. WordPress uses this same URL to generate IFRAME/Embed code, if we paste Share URL in visual editor...
4. Now we have another option to embed SoundCloud widget on any site by following `IFRAME` code.
5. Sample IFRAME code: `<iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/203809866&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>`
6. Now if you observe SRC, it has unique track ID value: `https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/203809866`
7. The rest of the parameters would remain same for any embed code

**My requirement**:
I want to use "Share" URL as an input to generate Track ID, exactly the same way WordPress does using oEmbed feature, for my own custom field.

Please note that I am not using ACF.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the track ID of any song via SoundCloud's JS API:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

// permalink to a track
var track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/alo-wala/the-coconut-song';

var myCustomFunction = function (track) {
  console.log( track ); // track.id gives you the ID of the song

  // @TODO
  // Do something with the song ID
};

SC.resolve(track_url).then(myCustomFunction);
</script>
```

Replace `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` with the ID of your [SoundCloud App](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps).

For more details: [SoundCloud API - Guide - SoundCloud URLs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#resolving).